# calculation of moment of inertia referred to motor shaft?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, inertia

Is this equation valid for a given mechanical system
[image: moto]

The Inertia of the motor is $J_m$,there is no loss in the system.then conservation of energy can be used.

the motor is revolving with speed $\omega$.and the gears ratio are equal.
$v $ is the velocity of the weight $w$

I am asking that the can the total InertIa can be expressed as  $$\frac{1}{2}J'_m\omega^2=\frac{1}{2}J_m\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$.

equivalent moment of inertia referred to the motor shaft is $J'_m$.

This was told by my teacher I think there is something wrong here.
I am skeptical about this because we can't talk about adding the both terms and referring them to as total inertia referred to motor shaft.